# Google Analytics - GA4 where can I view the event parameter values in event report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, analytics-events

I am firing a GA4 custom event.
I have added 2 event parameters to my event as below screenshot.

In debug view I am able to see the parameters with the values, but in Event reports like Engagement --> Events --> My event, I am not able to see the parameters and their valves, that I have set for this event.

How can I see them ? Am I trying to find them in wrong place ?

[image: Tag Set up]

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/138727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after some analysis - Need to set up a corresponding Custom Dimension for the event, so that in other event related reports we can see the event parameter values under the relevant dimension name.